# What does the word "curse" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Hamsun is not so well known in America—perhaps **the curse of a minor language**—but his influence is certainly felt.

What does *curse* mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

It is figurative.

The sentence suggests that had English (or French, or German, or Spanish) been Knut Hamsun's native language, he would have been a lot better known in English-speaking countries.

As it was, he was ***"cursed"*** with the fact that he had to write in a language (Norwegian) not too many people around the world are familiar with.